# Playing Hardcover and DDAL modules : Level up

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, organized-play

One of my player began a hardcover then played a DDAL module before finishing the chapter of the Hardcover. May he gain a level after the module and continue the hardcover with this new level ?

Comment: Are you playing in the actual Adventurers League, or just using their materials, but play at home?

Comment: @Mołot with those tags in place, I think we can take it at face value it's organized play.

Comment: @NautArch in Poland there are organized play places that use AL materials, but are not part of the official AL, so I hope you are right here, I would prefer to be sure :)

Comment: Yes, we are playing with the official material

Answer (score 5):

## Yes

This is answered in the  [FAQ_v9.1 of the Adventure League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack)

### Characters can play other adventures between sessions

They can level up and earn rewards playing other adventures between sessions.

> **Playing Content Between Sessions**
>
> Characters can play other adventures (including
> other multiple-session adventures) between sessions.
>
> Players taking their characters from game to game
> in this way **are permitted to advance in level** and earn
> rewards between sessions of a multiple-session
> adventure but must exercise caution or else they may
> accidentally level-out of their original game.

### Characters must be careful not to level out of the hardcover level range

> **Hardcover Adventures**
> A character can only play one hardcover adventure
> at a time. If character playing one adventure jumps
> into another hardcover from a different storyline,
> and levels outside of the first adventure’s level range,
> they can’t return to the first adventure.